# Import files in Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, python-import, relative-import

I have a flask app, inside the app I import some functions from another python files live on the same directory,
inside app.py
`from kafka_handler import KafkaReceiver, KafkaSender, logger`
and I have tests folder inside it I have BaseCase.py
`from src.app import app`
but when try to run the test using  `python3 -m unittest discover tests` I got this error  `from kafka_handler import KafkaReceiver, KafkaSender, logger ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kafka_handler'`
I have a docker image to run the application, what should I do to make the tests runs without breaking the application

```html
FROM python:3.11
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ENV PYTHONPATH=/app
COPY src /app

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

and the project tree is as the following

```
project
    src
       __init__.py
       pp.py
       kafka_hander.py
    tests
      __init__.py
      BaseCase.py
      test_something.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try prefix your import with a dot, `from .kafka_handler import KafkaReceiver, KafkaSender, logger`.
Find detailed information about relative imports in according section of this article:

```
https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/
```

Based on the information you provided, it seems that the BaseCase serves as `__main__` file and imports `app.py`. Therefore it needs to know the reference / path, where to find `kafka_handler.py`.

Comment: Yes, I use `src.kafka_handler` which is the same as `.kafka_handler`, thank you